# Does Firebase Storage have persistence capabilities in flutter?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-storage

I have an app in which I use firebase storage to provide videos to my users. I would want the users to experience some content offline as well, so does firebase storage have offline capabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is for your users to download videos and store the videos on their device's harddrive. According to [this documentation resource](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files), Google Firebase will let you download files from a Google Cloud Storage bucket.

The application may then need to access the local storage of the device and start/close video files locally.